I'm having trouble installing npm and Angular CLI within a Bitbucket Pipeline
The following commands execute just fine in my local development environment:
npm install -g
npm install -g @angular/cli


But here's what happens when I try to do this within a Bitbucket pipeline:
- step:
    name: Web Admin Portal Deployment
    caches:
      - node
    script:
      - cd Admin
      - npm install -g
      - npm install -g @angular/cli
      - ng build --configuration staging


+ npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "npm:": npm:string-width@^4.2.0
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-09-25T19_58_43_985Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "npm:": npm:string-width@^4.2.0
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2024-09-25T19_58_43_985Z-debug.log

No the truth is, although it did not break the script, the first npm install -g did not run cleanly, as it did on my local workstation. Here are the details, when I expand this section.
Any idea what I need to do to get this to runs cleanly within the Bitbucket pipeline? Thanks!
Edit: This might be a clue. I threw a command in there to output the version of node:
node -v

v8.9.4

Yikes! That's quite old! On my workstation I am running v20.15.1
How can I get a more recent version of Node installed in the pipeline?
+ npm install -g
npm WARN lifecycle esbuild@0.18.20~postinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) esbuild@0.18.20 node install.js /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/vite/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/android-arm@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/android-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/android-arm@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"android","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/android-x64@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/android-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/android-x64@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"android","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/sunos-x64@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/sunos-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/sunos-x64@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"sunos","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/linux-arm@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/linux-arm@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/win32-ia32@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/win32-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/win32-ia32@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/netbsd-x64@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/netbsd-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/netbsd-x64@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"netbsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/linux-ia32@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/linux-ia32@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/darwin-x64@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/darwin-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/darwin-x64@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/win32-x64@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/win32-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/win32-x64@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/freebsd-arm64@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/freebsd-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/freebsd-arm64@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/darwin-arm64@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/darwin-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/darwin-arm64@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/openbsd-x64@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/openbsd-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/openbsd-x64@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"openbsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/linux-s390x@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-s390x):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/linux-s390x@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"s390x"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/linux-loong64@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-loong64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/linux-loong64@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"loong64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/linux-ppc64@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-ppc64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/linux-ppc64@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ppc64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/android-arm64@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/android-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/android-arm64@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"android","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/win32-arm64@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/win32-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/win32-arm64@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/linux-arm64@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/linux-arm64@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/freebsd-x64@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/freebsd-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/freebsd-x64@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/linux-mips64el@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-mips64el):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/linux-mips64el@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"mips64el"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @esbuild/linux-riscv64@0.18.20 (../../../../../../opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/Admin/node_modules/esbuild/node_modules/@esbuild/linux-riscv64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @esbuild/linux-riscv64@0.18.20: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"riscv64"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.14.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@16.0.0 requires a peer of @angular/localize@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-mat-timepicker@17.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-mat-timepicker@17.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-mat-timepicker@17.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-mat-timepicker@17.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-mat-timepicker@17.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/animations@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-mat-timepicker@17.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-cookie-service@17.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-cookie-service@17.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^17.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@7.4.2 requires a peer of webpack@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vite@4.5.5 requires a peer of less@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vite@4.5.5 requires a peer of sass@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vite@4.5.5 requires a peer of stylus@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vite@4.5.5 requires a peer of terser@^5.4.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vite@4.5.5 requires a peer of sugarss@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vite@4.5.5 requires a peer of @types/node@>= 14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vite@4.5.5 requires a peer of lightningcss@^1.21.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
+ lightning-admin@0.0.0
added 129 packages in 23.533s


Words of wisdom, for any interested party - Supplying an answer, or a pointer in the right direction, is infinitely more useful than just dinging a question as "not useful". There are two logical possibilities. You either know the answer, or you don't. If you don't know the answer, then why do you judge the question as "not useful"? If you do know the answer, why don't you supply it?

The issue is the image which is defined right at the top of the yaml.
image: atlassian/whatever-...

I was using atlassian/default-image:2 which has node v8.9.4.
replacing that with atlassian/default-image:4, which has node v18.13.0, solved the problem.
Atlassian's images are listed here:
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-docker-images-as-build-environments/

Actually, as I worked through subsequent issues, I ultimately moved to an even higher version of node by specifying "image: node:20.15.1". (This is the version of node which I'm running on my development workstation.)
